# Search an element in associative array in php

Tags: php

I have this array....

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 72 
    [1] => 73 
    [2] => 74 
)
```

and i want to search these elements in multidimensional array which is given below.. and i want to compare with just "lead_image_id" as above array is actually array of "lead_image_id"

```
 Array 
 (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [lead_image_id] => 60
        [lead_image_name] => assets/images/logo.png
        [lead_image_lead_id] => 74
        [lead_image_status] => 0
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [lead_image_id] => 69
        [lead_image_name] => uploads/leads/5276.png
        [lead_image_lead_id] => 74
        [lead_image_status] => 0
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object (
        [lead_image_id] => 70
        [lead_image_name] => assets/images/logo.png
        [lead_image_lead_id] => 74
        [lead_image_status] => 0
    )
)
```

Comment: you should use two inner foreach

Comment: If you on wordpress just use this wp_list_pluck function https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck

Answer (score 3):

You can do this like now. There is 2 array firstarr is your first array and secarr is second associative array.

```
foreach($secarr as $secval){
    foreach($secaval as $val){
        if($val['lead_image_lead_id'] == $firstarr['value']){
            echo "match";
        }else{
            echo "not matched";
        }
    }
}
```